# Getting MongoParseError: Invalid message size: 1347703880, max allowed: 67108864

Tags: mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am building a RESTful BLogAPP where my stack is MEN
while connecting to mongo server i am getting this error

**These were working But this happened**

**My Mongo file code**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const url = "mongodb://localhost/127.0.0.1:27017/Blog";
mongoose.connect(url ,{ 

 useNewUrlParser: true,
 useUnifiedTopology: true
})
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.once("open", (_) => {
  console.log("Database connected:", url);
});

db.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error("connection error:", err);
});
module.exports =  mongoose;
```

**My app.js**

```
const mongoose = require("./server/mongoose");
```

Answer (score 7):

It was resolved for me after remove server port from connection string. Replace mongodb connection string From

```
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/Blog";
```

To

```
const url = "mongodb://localhost/Blog";
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message and I've finally solved it. Try to leave it like this:

```
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/Blog";
```

Answer (score 1):

I too got the same error while accessing MongoDB via mongoose.
The URI I set was `MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:3000/myDB`.
The port was wrong.

I solved it by correcting the Mongo URI.
`MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB`.